# Correcting mistakes in strings based on array of similar strings

Tags: text, grouping, fuzzy

Can somebody point to the right direction how to do this task: 
I have a lot of array of strings with such buckets:

- Somebody did that two years ago

  Somebody did th two years ago

  Somebody did that two years a

  Somedody d that two years ago

  Somebody that two years ago

And I need to get this: **Somebody did that two years ago**

Any links to algorithms or libs will be awesome. These strings came from OCR and sometimes OCR make mistakes in letter/words but I have 2-5 different spelling of same string.

**Update**
Based on suggestions from @alec_djinn I`ve found the python lib that can create "median" string based on Levenshtein distance. https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-median

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [sequence alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment) algorithm and then find the [consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_sequence) on the aligned sequences.

There are tons of libraries and software available but they are often suited for biological sequences only (DNA, RNA, proteins). One python library for general-string alignments is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alignment/

Once you have the sequences aligned, you can use the following (very basic) way of computing a consensus.

```
def compute_consensus(sequences):
    consensus = ''
    for i in range(len(sequences[0])):
        char_count = Counter()
        for seq in sequences:
            char_count.update(seq[i])
        consensus += char_count.most_common()[0][0]

    return consensus.replace('-','') #assuming '-' represent deleted letters
```

Where `sequences` is a list of aligned sequences. All aligned sequences should be of the same length.

Comment: It looks like the right way to do that. Thanks!! Do you know any libs for python around that?

Comment: You can try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alignment/ for general alignment. For the consensus, you can implement a simple consensus() function yourself by counting the number of any letter for each position of the aligned sequences and then picking the most counted one as consensus. If the noise in the sequences is lower than 25% it usually works very well.

Comment: I`ve found this one https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-median it can create "median" string based on Levenshtein distance. Thanks one more time!